# Excel Pivot table - how to use data and only have "pure truthy" results

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table, that looks like this (in tabular form, repeating labels, no values) :

| Index | inactive? |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | False |
| 3 | True |
| 4 | False |

It's coming from a large-ish dataset, looking at boolean fields. Clearly the only combinations possible for one index are "true", "false", or "True & False"

I want to just extract a list of "only trues"

How can this be done? Thank you :)